# How can I can insert the contents of a file into another file right before a specific line

Tags: sed

How can I can insert the contents of a file into another file right before a specific line using sed?

example I have file1.xml that has the following:

```
        <field tagRef="376">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="377">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="58">
        </field>
        <group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
    </fieldList>
</message>
```

and file2.xml has the following:

```
        <field tagRef="9647">
            <description>Offset</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9648">
            <description>Offset Units/Direction</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9646">
            <description>Anchor Price</description>
        </field>
```

how can I insert the contents of file2 into file1 just before

```
<group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
```

so it will look like this:

```
       <field tagRef="376">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="377">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="58">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9647">
            <description>Offset</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9648">
            <description>Offset Units/Direction</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9646">
            <description>Anchor Price</description>
        </field>
        <group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
    </fieldList>
</message>
```

I know how to insert after that line using

```
sed 'group ref="StandardMessageTrailer"/r file2.xml' file1.xml > newfile.xml
```

but I want to insert it before.

appreciate the help

Comment: I'd love to see an actual sed solution - I know it should be possible with something like `/StandardMessageTrailer/{x;r insert;G}` but that's not quite it...

Answer (score 23):

```
f2="$(<file2)"
awk -vf2="$f2" '/StandardMessageTrailer/{print f2;print;next}1' file1
```

if you want sed, here's one way

```
sed  -e '/StandardMessageTrailer/r file2' -e 'x;$G' file1
```

Comment: Your `sed` version doesn't print the last line of file1. If you add `-e '$G'` after the `'x'` then it will, but it will fail if the line with the regex is the last line in file1 by printing that line *then* the contents of file2.

Comment: @dennis thanks. with regard to the last line regex issue. i will bet on it not happening, for now. :) as you can see, my preferred solution is not sed.

Comment: On MacOS, you can write changes directly to the file by adding -i.bak to the command: `sed -i.bak -e '/StandardMessageTrailer/r file2' -e 'x;$G' file1`

Answer (score 4):

If you can bear to make two passes, you can use a marker:

```
sed '/Standard/i MARKER' file1.xml | sed -e '/MARKER/r file2.xml' -e '/MARKER/d'
```

The trouble with trying to do it in one pass is that there's no way (that I know of) other than 'r' to insert the contents of a file, and 'r' does so in the output stream, out of reach of manipulation, *after* sed is finished with the line. So if the 'Standard' is in the last line, whatever you do with it will be over by the time file2 appears.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do like this:

1. *file1*, file to read insert content
2. *file2*, insert reading content from *file1* to at the head of *file2*
3. script snippet:

   `sed "\$r ${file2}" ${file1} > tmpfile` 
   `mv tmpfile ${file2}`

Answer (score 1):

Here were the solutions that worked for me:

1. Using a marker like [explained in another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2516501/535203):

   ```
   sed '/StandardMessageTrailer/i MARKER' file1.xml | sed -e '/MARKER/r file2.xml' -e '/MARKER/d'
   ```
2. Counting the line when it occured [like explained in another reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141656/535203):

   ```
   LINE_NUMBER_MATCHING=$(sed -n '/StandardMessageTrailer/=' file1.xml) && sed "$((${LINE_NUMBER_MATCHING} - 1))r file2.xml" file1.xml
   ```
3. Or using sed [like explained in another reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142235/535203):

   ```
   sed $'/StandardMessageTrailer/{e cat file2.xml\n}' file1.xml
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the different solutions and the one from Beta did the work for me.

**Summary :**

- I wanted to insert different files into a main file
- I wanted to use markers to say where I wanted these files to be inserted

**Example :**
Create 2 files :

*cloud_config.yml:*

```
coreos:
__ETCD2__
```

*etcd2.yml :*

```
  etcd2:
    name:                         __HOSTNAME__
    listen-peer-urls:             http://__IP_PUBLIC__:2380
    listen-client-urls:           http://__IP_PUBLIC__:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379
```

Then we run that script on it :

```
sed '/Standard/i __ETCD2__' cloud_config.yml \
| sed -e "/__ETCD2__/r etcd2.yml" > tmpfile
sed "s|__ETCD2__||g" tmpfile > cloud_config.yml
```

**Finally, we got that :**

```
coreos:
  etcd2:
    name:                         __HOSTNAME__
    listen-peer-urls:             http://__IP_PUBLIC__:2380
    listen-client-urls:           http://__IP_PUBLIC__:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379
```

Answer (score 0):

personally, I prefer this solution. It is a bit slower than a single call, but easier to read for a programmer:

```
awk '/StandardMessageTrailer/{exit}{print}' file1.xml >output.xml  # lines until token
cat file2.xml >>output.xml  # the include file
awk '/StandardMessageTrailer/{o=1} o==1{print}' file1.xml >>output.xml  # lines from (and including) token
```

or the last command, if the token should not be included in the output:

```
awk 'o==1{print} /StandardMessageTrailer/{o=1}' file1.xml >>output.xml  # lines after token
```

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
      a[NR] = $0
      next
     } 
    /StandardMessageTrailer/{
      for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++) print a[i]
    }1
' file2.xml file1.xml

        <field tagRef="376">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="377">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="58">
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9647">
            <description>Offset</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9648">
            <description>Offset Units/Direction</description>
        </field>
        <field tagRef="9646">
            <description>Anchor Price</description>
        </field>
        <group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
    </fieldList>
</message>
```

Comment: this doesn't guarantee the output order at all

Comment: that only guarantees the indices are sequential to input row order, ***if*** you also print them out sequentially in the same direction. That `for(i in a)` doesn't guarantee that at all. The triple argument `for( )` construct could remedy this. Other ways would be using `gawk` and setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`, but that's not portable at all - only a sequential iteration of indices is.

Comment: this is actually one of the aspects i hate about the `posix` spec for `awk` - that you cannot even get array indices iterated in the same order you've added them (and this has nothing to do them being hashed key arrays - it takes close to no extra space and processing time for them to track the order, but a las, we have to make the best out of what we're dealt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are the inputs `file1` and `file2`...

```
---------
0x423A417F
0x42BED4B9
0x434367F3
---------

---------
abcd
xyzw
        <group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
    </fieldList>
</message>
---------
```

…this approach loads the full `file1` in 1 shot, then revert back to checking individual rows for `file2`, and simply prepends it when the search phrase is found

> ```
> mawk 'FNR == NR ? (__ = $_) * (RS = ORS)  \
>                 : !/StandardMessageTrailer/ || $!NF = __$_' RS='^$'
> ```

> ```
>  <( jot -w '0x%.8X' 3  1111114111 - 8688442 ) 
>  <( echo "abcd\nxyzw" |
>     mawk 'END {
>         print "        <group ref=\"StandardMessageTrailer\""\
>               " required=\"true\"/>\n    </fieldList>\n</message>" } 1' )
> ```

```
abcd
xyzw
0x423A417F
0x42BED4B9
0x434367F3
        <group ref="StandardMessageTrailer" required="true"/>
    </fieldList>
</message>
```

By using `RS = "^$"` instead of `RS = ""`, blank rows in `file1` will be fully preserved.