# Automatically inserting specified file into another (using sed, AWK, or Perl)

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

Let's say I have a file, `Foo.in`:

```
Contents of Foo
```

and `Bar.in`

```
INSERT Foo.in
Contents of Bar
```

I would like to write a `sed` script that replaces `INSERT xyz` with actual contents of the `xyz` file. In this particular example I'd like to produce `Bar.out` file containing:

```
Contents of Foo
Contents of Bar
```

I thought about using `sed`'s `r` command as demonstrated [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512362/how-can-i-can-insert-the-contents-of-a-file-into-another-file-right-before-a-spe), but the problem is that the name of the file to be inserted is specified in the file itself. I thought about scanning the file for `INSERT` commands and then running `sed` separately for every `INSERT` found, but that is a horrible solution with O(n^2) complexity. I'd prefer to do this using sed or AWK, but if all else fails a Perl script would be acceptable.

Comment: I would argue that to be O(n). More importantly though, unless you have thousands of files and need to this every other day, why care for the asymptotic complexity. If the problem really was bound by resources, neither script language would be the right answer. edit: Wait, is this about doing that for only one file? Then complexity is completely meaningless...

Comment: I have many files to process in that way and each may contain multiple lines. If I scan each file N times (where N is the number of of INSERT pragmas) then complexity is O(n^2), not O(n). I agree this is not a big issue here, but nevertheless it is an indication of a bad design.

Comment: As you mention, sed will not replace a dynamic content where content to insert is a value used as reference in the sed script. File name are "hardcoded". Now you can dynamicaly created a sed script but in this case, awk is a lot better

Comment: If n is the number of pragmas you are right, sorry. Nevertheless, in the world of scripts i would keep one sentence from the camel book in the back of my head: 'A Perl script is "correct" if it gets the job done before your boss fires you.' If you start thinking about runtime efficiency and resource management, Perl might be the wrong language and that is most likely just as true for sed and awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat Foo.in 
Contents of Foo

$ cat Bar.in 
INSERT Foo.in
Contents of Bar.in

$ awk '/INSERT/{while((getline line < $2) > 0 ){print line}close($2);next}1' Bar.in 
Contents of Foo
Contents of Bar.in
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this solution work recursively?

Comment: @Jan Stolarek I just posted in another post please have a look

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do. Here is a small Perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while(<>) {
  # If this line is an INSERT command, capture the filename and insert it
  if (my ($filename) = /^INSERT\s+(.+)$/) {
    open my $fh, "<", $filename;
    local $/;
    print <$fh>;
  }
  # Otherwise just print out the line as it is.
  else {
    print;
  }
}
```

Usage: `$ perl the-script.pl some_file.txt > output.txt`

There are some issues with this solution: `INSERT`s in an inserted file won't be processed. The file path in an `INSERT` is interpreted relative to the working directory of the invocation, not to the file that issued the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Amon using your regex,

```
perl -MFile::Slurp -pe '$_= read_file($1) if /^INSERT\s+(.+)$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Recursion

```
$ cat Foo.in
Contents of Foo
INSERT test

$ cat test
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat Bar.in
INSERT Foo.in
Contents of Bar.in
```

AWK code:

```
awk '
function fetch(inp){
                     while( (getline p < inp) > 0)
                     print p
                     close(inp)
                   }
           /INSERT/{
                    while((getline line < $2) > 0)
                    {
                     if(line ~ /INSERT/){
                                         split(line,A)
                                         fetch(A[2])
                                         next
                                        }
                                    else{
                                         print
                                        }
                    }
                     close($2)
                     next
                   }1
   ' Bar.in
```

Result:

```
INSERT Foo.in
1
2
3
4
5
Contents of Bar.in
```

**---Edit---**

```
$ cat test.awk
function fetch(inp){
                 while( (getline p < inp) > 0)
                 print p
                 close(inp)
               }
       /INSERT/{
                while((getline line < $2) > 0)
                {
                 if(line ~ /INSERT/){
                                     split(line,A)
                                     fetch(A[2])
                                     next
                                    }
                                else{
                                     print
                                    }
                }
                 close($2)
                 next
               }1
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f test.awk Bar.in
```

Comment: Hmm.. it looks like it doesn't work for me. I also tried putting this into a file and running `awk` with `-f` option but with no luck.

Comment: Try like this `awk -f test.awk Bar.in`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried. It doesn't seem to work :-/

Comment: check the content of your test files in your edit it looks like you removed `.in`, BTW what's the error message ?

Comment: No error message - simply nothing gets substituted. When I replace the recursive version with the original, non-recursive one all works fine.

Comment: I really could not find problem I checked with `gawk`, `mawk`  `original-awk` and `nawk`, one reason could be if file mentioned in column2 doesn't exist in present working directory, then it returns you nothing, but return contents of `Bar.in` have you missed anything while copying script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without loading Perl modules, in even fewer characters:

```
perl -pe 'open $F,"<$1" and $_=<$F> if /^INSERT\s+(.+)$/' [file]
```