# using sed to insert file content into a file BEFORE a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I'm new to `sed`, I'm trying to insert the content of a BFile into the file AFile, BEFORE a pattern (in AFile)

Hereafter's what I've tried :

`sed -i '/blah Blah/r BFile' AFile` : it's inserting the content of BFile AFTER the pattern in AFile.

`sed -i '/blah Blah/i BFile' AFile` : it's inserting the **string** 'BFile' BEFORE the pattern in AFile.

... hmmm

I'm conscious it's because of a wrong comprehension of regexp or `sed` : I can't understand how the `/i` and `/r` work here... I can't find any help in `sed --help`

Anyone understanding my point ?

Regards,

Stan

Comment: `man sed` to read manual.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed $'/blah Blah/{e cat BFile\n}' AFile
```

or:

```
sed -e 'N;/\n.*blah Blah/{r BFile' -e '};P;D' AFile
```

or as Alek pointed out:

```
sed '/blah Blah/e cat BFile' AFile
```

Comment: @NeronLeVelu this is a GNU sed specific command see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Why not just `sed '/blah Blah/e cat Bfile'`

Comment: This insert the contents of `BFile` on the *line* before the pattern. In my case I was trying to replace a pattern with a file. Which is `sed -e '/blah Blah/{r bar' -e 'd}'`.  It's worth noting the `r` command needs to be escaped by a newline or a separate -e  `...}`src https://askubuntu.com/a/540538/676225

Comment: @Alek I imagine invoking `cat` is would be less performant

Answer (score 5):

#### Content of `AFile`

```
one
two
three
blah Blah
four
```

#### Content of `BFile`

```
...b...
```

#### Run these commands

```
# get line number
$ sed -n '/blah Blah/=' AFile
4

# read file just before that line
$ sed '3r BFile' AFile
one
two
three
...b...
blah Blah
four
```

Comment: While all the other sed command do not work if it is the last line, this one does. However this does not work if it is the first line. :( I guess you should chain this using an or `|` and call sed a third time if its the first line.

Answer (score 5):

sed's r command does not change the pattern space. The file's content is printed at the end of the current cycle or when the next input line is read (info sed), therefore the N in the following command

```
sed '/blah Blah/ {
r Bfile
N
}' Afile
```

Comment: This answer is simpler without GNU sed.
NOTE: this doesn't work when `/blah Blah/` is the last line (with newline terminator) in `Afile`, because it will append `Bfile` **after**, not before `blah Blah`.

Answer (score 3):

**[Insert file contents into another file BEFORE pattern]**

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/r file1' -e //N file2
```

**[After Pattern]**

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/r file1' file2
```

Comment: //N is an amazing trick - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk:

Print Bfile before the matched line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /blah Blah/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' Bfile Afile
```

print Bfile after:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} {print} /blah Blah/{printf "%s", bfile}' Bfile Afile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/blah Blah/ r BFile;x;1!p;${g;p;}' AFile
```

buffer the current line so read BFile occur before printing the current line (that is print a next line in fact)

Answer (score 0):

Here were the solutions that worked for me:

1. Using a marker like [explained in another reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2516501/535203):

   ```
   sed '/blah Blah/i MARKER' AFile | sed -e '/MARKER/r BFile' -e '/MARKER/d'
   ```
2. Counting the line when it occured [like explained in another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26141656/535203):

   ```
   LINE_NUMBER_MATCHING=$(sed -n '/blah Blah/=' AFile) && sed "$((${LINE_NUMBER_MATCHING} - 1))r BFile" AFile
   ```
3. Or using sed [like explained in another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142235/535203):

   ```
   sed $'/blah Blah/{e cat BFile\n}' AFile
   ```