# Insert content from a file after specific pattern regex match by using sed in bash

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to insert multiple of lines from a text file before a particular text. I would like to use regex to select the particular text, and the text is like this:

```
//**insert_yannyann*//
```

『//**insert_yannyann*//』is in b.txt, and b.txt is just like that

```
...

//**insert_yannyann*//

...
```

a.txt is like that:

```
1234
5678
9101
```

For inserting a.txt text file before the pattern of text in b.txt , I tried this regex in ubuntu 18.04 bash command.

```
sed -n -i -e '\/\/**insert_yannyann*\/\/ /r a.txt' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' b.txt
```

even I tried another regex pattern.

```
sed -n -i -e '//?\s*\*[(?=.*\insert_yannyann\b)]*?\*\s*//? /r a.txt' -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' b.txt
```

but sed always show wrong message to me for the wrong regex I used.

I want to make b.txt be like that:

```
...

1234
5678
9101
//**insert_yannyann*//

...
```

I am certainly check two of these regex is correct by some online regex tools, but I don't understand why sed show wrong message to me.

```
\/\/**insert_yannyann*\/\/

//?\s*\*[(?=.*\insert_yannyann\b)]*?\*\s*//?
```

I'm not sure whether regex regulation is the same in different programming languages, could somebody explain why it is not correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using sed to insert file content into a file BEFORE a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141347/using-sed-to-insert-file-content-into-a-file-before-a-pattern)

Comment: regarding `online regex tools` they  are not suitable for `sed` because the regular expression feature and syntax is very different.. for ex: lookaround is not supported by sed

Comment: Oh~, I see, so I have better to try another method to approach the same effect?

Comment: there are various ways suggested in the duplicate question mentioned above, I feel `sed -e '\,//\*\*insert_yannyann\*//, { r a.txt' -e 'N}'` is good choice if you know the line to be matched cannot be last line in the file

Comment: uhnmmmm, OK. But I found it is better to use {} to separate file from regex rather than using "/xxx/xxx/", is it right?

Comment: And also could you please explain about what is the function of  <-e 'N> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Perl` may not be your option, but it's worth a try.
With Perl you can say:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'if ($. == 1) {$replace = $_; next} s#(?=//\*\*insert_yannyann\*//)#$replace#g; print' a.txt b.txt > b_new.txt
```

Then `b_new.txt` holds:

```
...

1234
5678
9101
//**insert_yannyann*//

...
```

**Explanations:**

- `-0777` option causes `Perl` to slurp whole files at once.
- `Perl` variable `$.` holds the input line number which is equivalent to the input file number in this usecase. With this value we can switch the processings for `a.txt` and `b.txt`.
- The `$replace = $_` statement assigns the variable `$replace` to the content of `a.txt`.
- The most important part will be the regex `s#(?=//\*\*insert_yannyann\*//)#$replace#g`. `Perl` regex supports a lookahead assertion with `(?=pattern)` notation. Thanks to this capability, we can easily insert a content just before the specified pattern.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

With AWK, you can do the similar thing:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {replace = replace $0 RS; next}
    {text = text $0 RS}
    END {
        print gensub(/\/\/\*\*insert_yannyann\*\/\//, replace "&", "g", text)
    }' a.txt b.txt > b_new.txt
```

The point is that the replacement string (the 2nd argument to `gensub()`) is a concatenation of `replace`, the content of a.txt, and `&` which represents the regex-matched string. Putting the variable `replace` prior to `&` causes the substitution *before* the matched pattern.

Comment: Oh! I see. but I have one more question. is there awk, grep also support looking function or only perl can do that?

Comment: Many other languages (PHP, ruby, python ..) and some tools (grep, find ..)
supports the `lookaround in regex`. Although AWK does not support it,
we can do the same thing. I've added the example in my answer. As a matter of fact, the `lookahead assertion` capability is not
essential for my script above because it slurps all lines *before*
applying the pattern matching with regex.
In the strict sense, `lookahead` in line-by-line processing would be
something like to make a decision depending on the next (unread) line,
which my usage does not apply.

Comment: Oh! I got it! sorry for my late reply for recently I'm working...It is the safe way to use "the same pattern" method than looking-forward method in some strict conditions. Thank you for teaching me this thing!

Comment: Note that `gensub()` is a GNU awk extension.