# Insert the contents of one file into another file before the line that matches a regular expression

Tags: awk, dockerfile, apache-tomee

In a DockerFile, I'm starting with a TomEE base image.  I need to modify the "conf/tomee.xml" to add a DataSource resource.  I've stored the DataSource definition in a separate file.  I want to find the "" end tag and insert the DataSource definition before that line.

I found [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512362/how-can-i-can-insert-the-contents-of-a-file-into-another-file-right-before-a-spe), which seems to be what I need, but for some reason this just isn't replacing the contents of the original file.  I tried piping the result to the file, but that results in a zero-length file (as if it's writing its output to stderr, which I can't believe).

Here is the original contents of "conf/tomee.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
  <!-- <Deployments dir="apps" /> -->
</tomee>
```

Here is the script I have so far:

```
    excerpt=$(<${TOMEE_HOME}/tomee.xml.excerpt)
awk -vexcerpt="${excerpt}" '/<\/tomee>/{print excerpt;print;next}1' ${TOMEE_HOME}/conf/tomee.xml
```

Here is the "tomee.xml.excerpt" file:

```
  # The SID may very well be sus2, but it could be something else.
  <Resource id="sus2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 10
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
       JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
       UserName = ${DB_USER}
       Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
  </Resource>
```

Note that this file has env var references.  That obviously won't work as written, but I will address that when I figure out how to get the excerpt file into the correct place in the tomee.xml file.

The following is what I see when I run the script manually:

```
+ excerpt='  # The SID may very well be sus2, but it could be something else.
  <Resource id="sus2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 10
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
       JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
       UserName = ${DB_USER}
       Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
  </Resource>'
+ awk '-vexcerpt=  # The SID may very well be sus2, but it could be something else.
  <Resource id="sus2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 10
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
       JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
       UserName = ${DB_USER}
       Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
  </Resource>' '/<\/tomee>/{print excerpt;print;next}1' /usr/local/tomee/conf/tomee.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
  <!-- <Deployments dir="apps" /> -->
  # The SID may very well be sus2, but it could be something else.
  <Resource id="sus2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 10
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
       JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
       UserName = ${DB_USER}
       Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
  </Resource>
</tomee>
```

When I inspect the "conf/tomee.xml" file, its contents haven't changed, including the last modification timestamp.

Comment: Awk normally prints to standard output.  If you have GNU Awk, you can use the `--inplace` option to update the file; otherwise, write to a temporary file, and move it back over the original.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers on the page you reference are wrong. Do this to print the contents of excerpt file exactly as-is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{excerpt=$0;next} {print} /<\/tomee>/{print excerpt}' RS='^$' "${TOMEE_HOME}/tomee.xml.excerpt" RS="\n" "${TOMEE_HOME}/conf/tomee.xml" > tmp && mv tmp "${TOMEE_HOME}/conf/tomee.xml"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS but you were already gawk-specific due to no space after `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

Side note on that topic: tomee.xml is one way to configure tomee but not very nice to dynamically configure the server, an alternative is to use conf/system.properties syntax this way you add the resource you want at the end without caring of XML:

```
db = new://Resource?type=DataSource
db.JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx:yyyy:zzzz
db.UserName = aaaaa
....
```

Comment: That does seem better, but I couldn't get that to work. I posted the following with the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982237/configuree-a-datasource-in-tomee-in-system-properties-instead-of-tomee-conf .