# Configure a DataSource in TomEE in system.properties instead of tomee.conf

Tags: apache-tomee

I'm able to configure a DataSource Resource in TomEE by modifying the "conf/tomee.xml" file.  However, it's sort of awkward to automate this modification, as I have to insert the DataSource definition before the "" line.  I heard from a comment in a [related SO posting from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966026/insert-the-contents-of-one-file-into-another-file-before-the-line-that-matches-a) that it's easier to append to the "system.properties" file.

So, I tried translating this:

```
<Resource id="sus2" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    MaxActive = 10
    MinIdle = 2
    MaxIdle = 2 
    MaxWait = 10000
   JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
   UserName = ${DB_USER}
   Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
</Resource>
```

Which works, to the following:

```
db = new://Resource?type=DataSource
db.id = Resource/sus2
db.JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.MaxActive = 10
db.MinIdle = 2
db.MaxIdle = 2 
db.MaxWait = 10000
db.JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_SID}
db.UserName = ${DB_USER}
db.Password = ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

which does not work.  It fails, saying it couldn't find the "Resource/sus2" resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration reference can be found at http://tomee.apache.org/ng/admin/configuration/resources.html

You have to understand that XML attributes becomes URI query parameters then I think it will work.

In other words:

```
db = new://Resource?type=DataSource
```

becomes

```
sus2 = new://Resource?type=DataSource
```

and your db.id doesn't do anything - I think it is logged.

In short: replace all your "db" by "sus2" and it will work

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll verify this later this morning.